# How to integrate MS teams video SDK in web application?

Tags: angular, azure, web-applications, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing a web application built using Angular. I've used Azure for application management. The users of my web site need to interact with each other by Video. So to achieve video functionality in my web site I'm using Microsoft Teams. I'm trying to integrate MS teams' video UI in my web app, here I need to add more icons to the User Interface. How to customize MS team' user interface with more functions and icons with different functionalities. How can I change the layout structure, modify the icons and add new items to teams in my web application?

How to integrate MS teams video SDK in web application?

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to use [Azure communication services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview). Please go through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview) to understand more about how to use and features available in it.

We have samples available as well so that you can have smooth understanding of how things work, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/overview#samples). Go through the samples to understand look and feel you can have.

The sample that I think would be best for you is - [The Web Calling sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/samples/web-calling-sample)